# JTAG not erase entire flash memory in code composer studio with MSP-FET

Tags: msp430, flash, debugging, jtag

I am using MSP430F2619 for storing device specific parameters in internal Flash memory using flash write routines.

while debugging using JTAG MSP-FET I found that my flash is getting written during debug session. But when I reload the program next time using JTAG previously written flash memory segments are erased by debugger.

Is it possible to set JTAG such that it will not overwrite this segment of program memory?

I am using code composer studio 6.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. In Code Composer, Go to Debug Configurations, then select Target, then MSP430 properties. There are five options, depending on whether you want to erase main memory only, or main and information memory, or protected memory etc. See below:
[image: Debug Configurations Dialog Box]

Comment: I am not using information memory to store my device configuration file but I am using one of the segment of **Main** memory and I want JTAG not to erase this particular segment

Comment: What you want to do is exactly what information memory is for. Unless your parameters need more space than the information memory can offer, that's almost certainly the best solution. I don't think that there is a way to do specifically what you ask, at least not with CCS.